# i get 404 on octobercms backend

Tags: octobercms

I installed october cms on ubuntu 16.04.

Did the installer, everything goes well, but when I try to go to the backend I get the 404 error.

I googled and did everything I could found:

1. Uncommented RewriteBase / on .htaccess
2. Enabled the rewrite module
3. Added "AllowOverride All" on the .conf site file

What can I do to fix this? Help!

Comment: Please share your configuration with us. How did you install octobercms?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution might be to check URL/URI, provided in address bar of your browser. It needs to agree with your configuration in config/cms.php
(for your reference: https://github.com/octobercms/october/blob/master/config/cms.php#L39 )

Answer (score 1):

For me it required making sure to make sure I had `AllowOverride all` in the `<Directory /var/www>` directive in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. It was set to None by default and was overriding all the allow I put in my vhost.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is not rewriting index.php to / then backend is accessible using the following url pattern:

```
virtualhost.october/index.php/backend/
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using IIS, you would need to add a web.config file with the following rewrite rules to get the backend working -

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```